# how to return toggle parameters without any condition javascript

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me to solve this?
actually i got an interview and they said to me to solve this?

i have a function with single parameters and in function i have 2 hard coded value
like var a = 20, b = 30

the Question is how to return second value when i pass first value and  the same how to return first value when i pass second parameter
But
without any condition like 'if', 'ternary', 'switch'

```
function someFn(x){
    var a = 20, b = 30;
    // Some logic
}
// to get - someFn(20) === 30 && someFn(30) === 20
```

Comment: I'd rather get mad at them and tell them to use language features for their intended purpose.  Did they provide you any extra context?  If I'm understanding correctly they want (from your example) `func(20)` to return `30` and `func(any_other_value)` to return `20`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I find your question a little unclear (it would be better if you post your attempt at solving the problem), and there's syntax issues in the code you've provided, you can solve this by using an object literal as a dictionary to map the variables dynamically to each other:

```js
function x(n) {
  let a = 20, b = 30;
  
  return {
    [a]: b,
    [b]: a
  }[n]
}

console.log(x(20)) // 30
console.log(x(30)) // 20
console.log(x(0)) // undefined
```

Or, in one line with ES6:

```
const x = n => ({20:30,30:20}[n])
```

---

If you want to get fancy - use principles of functional programming and partial application:

```js
const swap = (a, b) => n => ({[a]:b,[b]:a}[n])

const swap20and30 = swap(20, 30)

console.log(swap20and30(30)) // 20
console.log(swap20and30(20)) // 30

const swapAandB = swap('A', 'B')

console.log(swapAandB('A')) // 'B'
console.log(swapAandB('B')) // 'A'
```

Comment: Thanks dear, this is what i want you are genious :)

Answer (score 4):

I just found out a simple logic; just add the two variable inside function and then subsctract the parameter value. simple

```js
function toggle(x){
    var a = 20, b = 30;
    return ((a+b)-x)
}
var return_value = toggle(30)
console.log(return_value)
var return_value = toggle(20)
console.log(return_value)
```

Comment: it can not work with string but it is perfect with numbers, thanks

Answer (score 2):

return a+b-x

You can add the two numbers and subtract the incoming number.

Comment: a+b-x can not work with string but it is perfect with numbers, thanks

Comment: Simplest solution, Thanks